# @ControllerAdvice annotated class is not catching the exception thrown in the service layer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, exception

I'm trying to centralize the error handling in my spring boot app. Currently i'm only handling one potential exception (NoSuchElementException), this is the controller advice:

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;

@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionController {

    @ExceptionHandler(NoSuchElementException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public DispatchError dispatchNotFound(NoSuchElementException exception) {
        System.out.println("asdasdasd");
        return new DispatchError(exception.getMessage());
    }
}
```

And here's the service which throws the exceptions:

```
import java.util.List;

import com.deliveryman.deliverymanapi.model.entities.Dispatch;
import com.deliveryman.deliverymanapi.model.repositories.DispatchRepository;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class DaoService {

    @Autowired
    DispatchRepository dispatchRepo;

    public Dispatch findByShipmentNumber(long shipmentNumber) {
        return dispatchRepo.findById(shipmentNumber).orElseThrow();
    }

    public List<Dispatch> findByUser(String user, String status) {
        if(status == null) {
            return dispatchRepo.findByOriginator(user).orElseThrow();
        } else {
            return dispatchRepo.findByOriginatorAndStatus(user, status).orElseThrow();
        }
    }

    public Dispatch createDispatch(Dispatch dispatch) { //TODO parameter null check exception
        return dispatchRepo.save(dispatch);
    }

}
```

The problem is that once I send a request for an inexistent resource, the json message shown is the spring's default one. It should be my custom json error message (DispatchError).

Now, this is fixed by adding a @ResponseBody to the exception handler method but the thing is that I was using an old code of mine as reference, which works as expected without the @ResponseBody annotation.

Can someone explain me why this is happening?

Comment: Which class is throwing the `NoSuchElementException`?

Comment: Matheus, the service class with the orElseThrow() of the Optional class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either annotate your controller advice class with `@ResponseBody`

```
@ControllerAdvice
@ResponseBody
public class ExceptionController {
   ...
```

or replace `@ControllerAdvice` with `@RestControllerAdvice`.

Tested and verified on my computer with source from your controller advice.

From source for `@RestControllerAdvice`

```
@ControllerAdvice
@ResponseBody
public @interface RestControllerAdvice {
  ...
```

Hence, `@RestControllerAdvice` is shorthand for

```
@ControllerAdvice
@ResponseBody
```

From source doc for `@ResponseBody`

> Annotation that indicates a method return value should be bound to the
> web response body. Supported for annotated handler methods.

Alternative using `@ControllerAdvice` only:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandlerAdvice {

    @ExceptionHandler(NoSuchElementException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<DispatchError> dispatchNotFound(NoSuchElementException exception) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new DispatchError(exception.getMessage()), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

I do have a theory on what's going on in your old app. With the advice from your question, and the error handler below, I can create a behaviour where the `DispatchError` instance appears to be returned by advice (advice is executed), but is actually returned by error controller.

```
package no.mycompany.myapp.error;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.boot.web.error.ErrorAttributeOptions;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.error.ErrorAttributes;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.error.ErrorController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;

@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ErrorHandler implements ErrorController {

    private static final String ERROR_PATH = "/error";
    private final ErrorAttributes errorAttributes;

    @RequestMapping(ERROR_PATH)
    DispatchError handleError(WebRequest webRequest) {
        var attrs = errorAttributes.getErrorAttributes(webRequest, ErrorAttributeOptions.of(ErrorAttributeOptions.Include.MESSAGE));
        return new DispatchError((String) attrs.get("message"));
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return ERROR_PATH;
    }
}
```

Putting an implementation of `ErrorController` into classpath, replaces Spring's `BasicErrorController`.

When reinforcing `@RestControllerAdvice`, error controller is no longer in effect for `NoSuchElementException`.

In most cases, an `ErrorController` implementation that handles all errors, in combination with advice exception handlers for more complex exceptions like `MethodArgumentNotValidException`, should be sufficient. This will require a generic error DTO like this

```
package no.mycompany.myapp.error;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Map;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class ApiError {

    private long timestamp = new Date().getTime();
    private int status;
    private String message;
    private String url;
    private Map<String, String> validationErrors;

    public ApiError(int status, String message, String url) {
        this.status = status;
        this.message = message;
        this.url = url;
    }

    public ApiError(int status, String message, String url, Map<String, String> validationErrors) {
        this(status, message, url);
        this.validationErrors = validationErrors;
    }
}
```

For `ErrorHandler` above, replace `handleError` with this

```
    @RequestMapping(ERROR_PATH)
    ApiError handleError(WebRequest webRequest) {
        var attrs = errorAttributes.getErrorAttributes(webRequest, ErrorAttributeOptions.of(ErrorAttributeOptions.Include.MESSAGE));
        return new ApiError(
                (Integer) attrs.get("status"),
                (String) attrs.get("message"), // consider using predefined message(s) here
                (String) attrs.get("path"));
    }
```

Advice with validation exception handling

```
package no.mycompany.myapp.error;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.validation.FieldError;
import org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestControllerAdvice;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@RestControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandlerAdvice {

    private static final String ERROR_MSG = "validation error";

    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    ApiError handleValidationException(MethodArgumentNotValidException exception, HttpServletRequest request) {

        return new ApiError(
                HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value(),
                ERROR_MSG,
                request.getServletPath(),
                exception.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors().stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                            FieldError::getField,
                            FieldError::getDefaultMessage,
                            // mergeFunction handling multiple errors for a field
                            (firstMessage, secondMessage) -> firstMessage)));
    }
}
```

Related config in *application.yml*

```
server:
  error:
    include-message: always
    include-binding-errors: always
```

When using *application.properties*

```
server.error.include-message=always
server.error.include-binding-errors=always
```

When using Spring Data JPA, consider using the following setting for turning off a second validation.

```
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      javax:
        persistence:
          validation:
            mode: none
```

More information on exception handling in Spring:

https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc (revised April 2018)
https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring (December 31, 2020)

Comment: The reference code is not using ResponseEntity is the same as my actual code; returning the unwrapped pojo. I'm satisfied with your answer but not completely, I'm expecting a more in depth explanation of how spring is capturing this exceptions and how it knows when to use the default exception handle or the customized.

Comment: @EdgarHernandez: I feel the topic is kind of too extensive for a SO answer. Do you mind if I send you this link to a well written article on the topic? The article was revised in 2018. https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc BR

Comment: @EdgarHernandez: Thanks for accepting my answer. I've added some more code to my answer that you may find useful. BR